# Am I executing the command with switches wrong, or is the code broken in OfficeToPDF?

Tags: .net

I downloaded [OfficeToPDF.exe](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF/releases/tag/release-1.8) to convert some DOCM files into PDF. I can do that with the following command. `OfficeToPDF asd.docm out.pdf`
Here is the link for [documentation](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF#command-line-switches) on command line switch options.

As soon as I am trying to add any command switches, the command doesn't work and returns this

> Input file can not be handled. Must be Word, PowerPoint, Excel, Outlook, Publisher or Visio

Examples I tried:

```
OfficeToPDF /verbose asd.docm out.pdf
OfficeToPDF /bookmarks /hidden /readonly asd.docm out.pdf
```

First command was my main goal as starters, but no matter in which order do i put in the command it sends the same invalid input message.
Second command was literally copied from documentation. (If you execute simply OfficeToPDF it will give back the help information, which has the line `OfficeToPDF.exe [/bookmarks] [/hidden] [/readonly] input_file [output_file]`)

Looking at the example in help information, it does not make any sense to me. Why isn't input file in []? If output and input is different why are we inserting them the same way? Does this code (apart from the already confirmed basic functionality) even work for anyone?

Comment: This isn't a question about programming. Don't you think you should ask it somewhere else?

Comment: well command syntax is programming to me, but if you know  a better place pls do share. @PalleDue

Comment: also with github link you can check code to help me input my variables. Did you even try to help?

Comment: No, I didn't. I found that it was outside the scope of stackoverflow. But I can tell you that placing a parameter in `[]` means it's optional. It wouldn't make sense if the input file was optional.

Comment: which site should i use for this question then? also did you read my post? this is not about input file, that is just another thing i do not understand from their documentation. My interest is in how to use command with its switches.

Comment: well flag it then, if that makes you happy, but i did include source code so you could look into that